# New instance of a class contains older data given to an older instance

Tags: python, pandas, oop, garbage-collection, vader

I'm trying to analyze some reviews using `vader` in `python`. I made an `Analyzer` class like so:

```
class Analyzer:
    dataframe = None
    reviews = []
    
    # other data

    def __init__(self, brand):
        self.dataframe = pd.read_csv(brand) # using pandas
        reviews = self.dataframe['Reviews'].tolist()

    def analyze(self):
        # code for analyze...

    # more codes...
```

and I used this class in `main.py` like so:

```
from analyzer import Analyzer

brands = [
    'apple',
    'google',
    'huawei',
    'motorola',
    'nokia',
    'samsung',
    'sony',
    'xiaomi'
]

for brand in brands:
    analysis = Analyzer(brand)
    analysis.analyze()
    del analysis
```

now the problem is:
When brands are given to the class to be analyzed, the older reviews remain in the list.

e.g.:
apple.csv has 1000 reviews and google.csv has 700 reviews. but when google is passed to analyzer, the `reviews` list length is not 700, but 1700.

Comment: Title was mind-boggling for me, after reading your question: It is `instance` not `intense`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reviews` attribute is for `class` and not `object`, since you defined it in the body of the class.
define the `reviews` in the body of `__init__`:

```py
class Analyzer:
    
    # other data

    def __init__(self, brand):
        self.dataframe = pd.read_csv(brand) # using pandas
        self.reviews = self.dataframe['Reviews'].tolist()

    def analyze(self):
        # code for analyze...

    # more codes...
```